# Octave legend symbols size differ from plot size

Tags: plot, octave, legend

The size of the symbols on the legend is different from the size on the plot. The symbol used for the decision boundary in the legend has the same linewidth as the plot but the crosses in the legend have a different linewidth than the plotted crosses.

[image: Plot]

This is the code I used to generate the plot.

```matlab
clear;

rand ("seed", 158);

data1x = rand(1,30);
data1y = rand(1,30);

data2x = 1+rand(1,30);
data2y = 1+rand(1,30);

dbx = 0:0.1:1.5;
dby = (-2/1.5).*dbx+2

plot(data1x,data1y,'x','linewidth', 3);
hold on;
plot(data2x,data2y,'x','linewidth', 3);
plot(dbx,dby,'k','linewidth', 2);
legend("Negative", "Positive", "Decision boundry");
legend("location","east");
set(gca,"linewidth", 2, "fontsize", 20);
axis("nolabel");

hold off;


saveas(1,"Diagram2.svg","svg");
```

Is there a way to fix this so that the linewidth of the symbols in the legend are identical to the ones plotted?

Comment: @CrisLuengo i have added the code and some comments.

Comment: I just ran your exact code (copied and pasted with no changes) on my installation and it plotted the legend symbols correctly (i.e. the same as the plot symbols). I tried it with all three graphics toolkits - qt (default), fltk and gnuplot. The gnuplot symbols were slightly different but the ones on the legend were still the same as those on the plot. Are you perhaps using an older version of Octave? Mine is version 5.2.0 on Xubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.